# decrypt C# encrypted string in PHP (StringCipher Library)

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes, rijndael

I want to decrypt a string which i encrypted with c# using the [StringCipher Library](https://github.com/marcolew/StringCipher/blob/master/StringCipher/StringCipher.cs)

what I have tried so far without success:

```
function decrypt($cipherText, $passPhrase)
{
    $Keysize = 256;
    $DerivationIterations = 1000;
    $cipher_algo = "aes-256-cbc";
    //$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher_algo));

    $cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = base64_decode($cipherText);
    $saltStringBytes = substr($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv, 0, ($Keysize / 8));
    $ivStringBytes = substr($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv, ($Keysize / 8), ($Keysize / 8));
    $cipherTextBytes = substr($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv, (($Keysize / 8) * 2), strlen($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv) - (($Keysize / 8) * 2));

    $keyBytes = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $passPhrase, $saltStringBytes, $DerivationIterations, ($Keysize / 8), true);
    return openssl_decrypt($cipherTextBytes, $cipher_algo, $keyBytes, 0, $ivStringBytes);
}
```

Comment: `StringCipher` uses Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits, see [here](https://github.com/marcolew/StringCipher/blob/master/StringCipher/StringCipher.cs#L34). OpenSSL does not support this algorithm, but only AES (AES is a subset of Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits), so your implementation is *not* compatible. A PHP library that supports Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits is e.g. [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/symmetric#streamcipher-vs-blockcipher).

Comment: Even if i switch to 128 bit, i'm not able to decrypt it. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A guess: In `openssl_decrypt()` use `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` as 4th parameter instead of 0. For 0 a Base64 encoded ciphertext is expected, which is not true in your case. If it still doesn't work, debug your code and check if salt, IV, actual ciphertext and the key generated with pbkdf2 are the same for decryption as for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The [128-bit variant](https://github.com/nopara73/DotNetEssentials/blob/master/DotNetEssentials/Crypto/StringCipher.cs) in PHP:

```
<?php

class StringCipher
{
    private const Keysize = 128;
    private const DerivationIterations = 1000;
    private const cipher_algo = "aes-128-cbc";

    public static function Encrypt($plainText, $passPhrase)
    {
        $saltStringBytes = self::Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        $ivStringBytes = self::Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        $keyBytes = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $passPhrase, $saltStringBytes, self::DerivationIterations, (self::Keysize / 8), true);
        $cipherTextBytes = $saltStringBytes . $ivStringBytes . openssl_encrypt($plainText, self::cipher_algo, $keyBytes, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivStringBytes);
        return base64_encode($cipherTextBytes);
    }

    public static function Decrypt($cipherText, $passPhrase)
    {
        $cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = base64_decode($cipherText);
        $saltStringBytes = substr($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv, 0, (self::Keysize / 8));
        $ivStringBytes = substr($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv, (self::Keysize / 8), (self::Keysize / 8));
        $cipherTextBytes = substr($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv, ((self::Keysize / 8) * 2), strlen($cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv) - ((self::Keysize / 8) * 2));
        $keyBytes = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $passPhrase, $saltStringBytes, self::DerivationIterations, (self::Keysize / 8), true);
        return openssl_decrypt($cipherTextBytes, self::cipher_algo, $keyBytes, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivStringBytes);
    }

    private static function Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy()
    {
        return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::cipher_algo));
    }
}
```